# Error while Installing APK

Tags: android, gradle

Today, I have updated my android studio from gradle  2.2.1 to 2.14.1
from that onwards my studio is unable install any apk files in the device.
  it showing the error.

```
\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK.
```

But on the explorer the directory contains apk file. I have tried clean,  rebuild & restared the studio also, but unable to fix. please help me.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: use `2.2.0` .Clean-Rebuild

Comment: please tell me how to change it

Answer (score 0):

click on option to solve your error
[image]

Comment: @kashyap build your project

Comment: Hi Mehra, i have build the project but still i am unable to install the apk file

Comment: Is the filename of apk is same as app-debug.apk ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing gradle version to previous state. in 
**File-->project structure-->Project -->Gradle version & Android plugin version.**